# While loading the data from csv file into oracle db using python code True value is displaying as 1 and false value is displaying as 0

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, oracle, dataframe, cx-oracle

While loading the data from csv file into oracle db using python code. After loading data into oracle db True value is displaying as 1 and false value is displaying as 0
Iam using following python code:

```html
import cx_Oracle as orcCon
from cx_Oracle import DatabaseError
import pandas as pd
import csv

csv_input=pd.read_csv(r"E:\Python_projects\test\python1.csv",index_col=False,na_values=" ").fillna('')
#csv_input.head()
#print(csv_input)

try:
    conn = orcCon.connect('scott/tiger@localhost:1522/orcl',encoding="UTF-8")
    if conn:
        print("cx_Oracle version:", orcCon.version)
        print("Database version:", conn.version)
        print("Client version:", orcCon.clientversion())
        
        # Now execute the sqlquery 
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        print("You're connected.................")
        print("TRUNCATING THE TARGET TABLE")
        cursor.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE PYTHON_TESTING")
        print("Inserting data into table")
        for i,row in csv_input.iterrows():
            sql = "INSERT INTO PYTHON_TESTING(C1,C2,C3)VALUES(:1,:2,:3)"
            cursor.execute(sql, tuple(row))
            # the connection is not autocommitted by default, so we must commit to save our changes
            conn.commit()
            #print("Record inserted successfullly")
except DatabaseError as e:
    err, = e.args
    print("Oracle-Error-Code:", err.code)
    print("Oracle-Error-Message:", err.message)

finally:
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()
```

I have created testing csv file as:

[image]

When data loaded into Oracle Table Data is displaying as:

[image]

Iam using python 3.9.2

Comment: Please [edit] the question with a [MRE] including: the `CREATE TABLE` statement for the table; and your expected output. Oracle does not have a boolean data type in SQL so it is unclear why you are surprised that the output is different (unless you are expecting the strings `'TRUE'` and `'FALSE'`)?

Comment: I have used :  CREATE TABLE PYTHON_TESTING
(
C1         VARCHAR2(30), 
C2         VARCHAR2(30), 
C3         VARCHAR2(30)
);

Comment: Iam expecting the output same as Csv file

Comment: If in Excel you put `FALSE` into A1 and `0` into B1 and `=A1=B1` into C1 then C1 is `TRUE`. Why do you expect a boolean to map to the string literal `'TRUE'` or `'FALSE'` rather than the numeric representation `1` and `0`?

Comment: If you add `print(row)` in the inner loop then do you get `true`/`false` values or are they `1`/`0` values?

Comment: Iam getting following output:

Comment: COLUMN 1    True
COLUMN2     True
COLUMN3     True
Name: 0, dtype: bool
COLUMN 1    False
COLUMN2     False
COLUMN3     False
Name: 1, dtype: bool
COLUMN 1    True
COLUMN2     True
COLUMN3     True
Name: 2, dtype: bool
COLUMN 1    False
COLUMN2     False
COLUMN3     False
Name: 3, dtype: bool
COLUMN 1    True
COLUMN2     True
COLUMN3     True
Name: 4, dtype: bool
COLUMN 1    False
COLUMN2     False
COLUMN3     False
Name: 5, dtype: bool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are converting a Python `bool` data type to an (Oracle dialect) SQL `VARCHAR2` data type. In SQL, Oracle does not have a concept of a boolean so there must be some mapping from one data type to another and the typical mapping use is `True => 1` and `False => 0` (if, in Python you try `True == 1` then the output is `True` but if you try `True == 'True'` then the output is `False`).

So your Python code is mapping `bool` to an integer and passing it to Oracle and then Oracle is making an implicit cast from the number to a string.

You need to break the chain of implicit casts and make an explicit cast to the string values you are expecting.

One way would be to map the numeric truthy values to string literals and can use:

```sql
INSERT INTO PYTHON_TESTING(C1,C2,C3)
VALUES(
  CASE :1 WHEN 1 THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END,
  CASE :2 WHEN 1 THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END,
  CASE :3 WHEN 1 THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END
);
```

Another way would be, in Python, to covert your tuple values from `bool` to strings; something like:

```py
cursor.execute(sql, tuple('TRUE' if col else 'FALSE' for col in row))
```

Comment: If that answer solved your issue then you should accept it. This helps future questioners have the same or similar issues and removes the question from he unanswered queue. Please do no leave successfully answered questions as unanswered.